# Delete the value of a dictionary if the value is the key in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, set

I have a dictionary and I want to delete each value of the dictionary which is the key.
I want this output: `G = {'y': {'z'}, 'z': {'u', 'f', 'y'}, 'u': {'z'}}`

```
G = {'y': {'z', 'y'}, 'z': {'z', 'u', 'f', 'y'}, 'u': {'u', 'z'}}
```

I tried this but I know. It's wrong.

```
for key,value in G.items():
    if key == value:
        del value
```

Comment: Your code isn't modifying the actual dict, just a temporary variable `value`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't modifying the dictionary, but a variable `value`. In addition, you don't want to look for *equality* of keys and values, you want to check if your key is `in` your set value. Then remove it from your set via [`set.remove`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.remove). So you can use:

```
for key, value in G.items():
    if key in value:
        G[key].remove(key)

print(G)

{'y': {'z'}, 'z': {'u', 'y', 'f'}, 'u': {'z'}}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`set.discard`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.discard), which doesn't give `KeyError` if the value does not exist in your set. The `if` condition may therefore be omitted.

```
for key, value in G.items():
    G[key].discard(key)
```

Finally, consider the below dictionary comprehension, which creates a *new* dictionary and assigns it to `G`. This is not intrinsically inefficient: time complexity will be the same as the above methods. This version uses [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.difference), here via its syntactic sugar `-`:

```
G = {k: v - {k} for k, v in G.items()}
```

As per @JonClements' comment, a one-line version which maintains references to `G` is possible via [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

```
G.update({k: v - {k} for k, v in G.items()})
```

Comment: Your last example could update G in place and use `set.difference` instead of rebuilding the set value, eg: `G.update((k, v.difference((k,))) for k, v in G.items())`

Comment: @JonClements, Yup true, I think `{k: v - {k} for k, v in G.items()}` would work too.

Comment: Yup... was going to suggest that - nice one... Although, if the dict G refers to has multiple references and all of them should reflect the changes, then you'll want `.update`...

Answer (score 0):

Delete the key in the value, not the value itself.

```
for key, value in G.items():
    if key in value:
        value.remove(key)
```